# Finding sum of numbers in the cells of an array within a range

Tags: java, arrays, optimization

I am preparing for a coding competition. In the archives I found this question:

You are given a sequence of N positive integers i1, i2, …, iN. In addition, you are given a starting integer b and lower and upper integer limits min and max, respectively. Note that 0 ≤ min ≤ b ≤ max always.

The sequence game is played as follows. Initially, your score is b. In step 1, you can either add i1 to b or subtract i1 from b to get a new scoreb1. In step 2, you update b1 by adding or subtracting i2 to get a new score b2. Proceeding in this way, in step j, you update bj-1 by adding or subtracting ij to get a new score bj. The rule is that each score bj should always lie between min and max, inclusive: that is, for each j, 1  ≤  j  ≤ N, it should be the case that min  ≤  bj  ≤  max. Your final score is bN, after using the last number in the sequence.

Your aim is to maximise your final score while playing according to the rules. If there is no way to complete all N steps without going outside the bounds min and max, your score is -1.

For example, suppose the sequence of numbers you have is [2,3,4], b is 5,min is 0 and max is 8. After step 1, the score can be 3 or 7. After step 2, the score can be 0, 4, or 6. A score of 10 is not allowed since max is 8. After step 3, the score can be 0, 2, 4, or 8. Thus, in this game, the maximum score you can obtain at the end of the sequence is 8.

Input format

The first line of the input contains four integers N, b, min and max, whose meaning is as explained above. The second line of input contains N space separated integers, the sequence over which the game is played.

Output format

Your output should be a single line consisting of one integer, the maximum final score that you can achieve.

Testdata

In all cases, N ≤ 103 and 0 ≤ min ≤ b ≤ max ≤ 103.

Sample Input

```
3 5 0 8 2 3 4
```

Sample Output

```
8
```

---

Now, I tried solving this problem by using a recursive technique but its too slow. I checked all the possible arrangements. Maybe that's where I went wrong. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

class seq2

{

    public static void recursive(int ar[],int turn,int sum,int max,int min,int n,int mega[])

    {

        if(turn!=n)

        {

            if(ar[turn]+sum<=max)

            {

                sum=sum+ar[turn];

                recursive(ar,turn+1,sum,max,min,n,mega);

                sum=sum-ar[turn];

            }

            if(sum-ar[turn]>=0)

            {

                sum=sum-ar[turn];

                recursive(ar,turn+1,sum,max,min,n,mega);

                sum=ar[turn]+sum;

            }

            if((ar[turn]+sum>max)&&(sum-ar[turn]<min))

            {

                sum=-1;

            }

        }

        else

        {

            if(sum>mega[0])

            {

                mega[0]=sum;

            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException

    {

        DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);

        int n=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        int b=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        int min=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        int max=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        System.out.println();

        int ar[]=new int[n],a;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)

        {

             a=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

             ar[i]=a;

        }

        int mega[]={-1};

        recursive(ar,0,b,max,min,n,mega);

        System.out.println(mega[0]);

    }

}
```

---

Can anyone suggest a better technique for solving this?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void recursive(int ar[], int turn, int sum, int max, int min, int mega[])
{
    int plus, minus;
    if (turn != ar.length)
    {
        plus = sum + ar[turn];
        if (plus <= max)
            recursive(ar, turn + 1, plus, max, min, mega);

        minus = sum - ar[turn];
        if (minus >= min)
            recursive(ar, turn + 1, minus, max, min, mega);
    }
    else if (sum > mega[0])
        mega[0] = sum;
}
```

managed to reduce time in 30%

Comment: Thanks aviad but even after your help, it cant computer the result for arrays having just 50 cells 

Comment: Thanks aviad but even after your help, the program cannot compute the result for arrays having just 50 cells

Comment: why? what's the problem? it does'nt seem to consume much space

Comment: As far as i can guess,the problem is that I'm using a recursive method which goes through every possible outcome and when it comes to arrays with too many cells, the running time increases exponentially. That is why I consider my code inefficient. If you could suggest a better approach, it would be a great help.

Comment: I'm almost sure that this problem is NP-hard, meaning no polynomial time algorithm exists for solving it

Comment: You could use binary integer programming to model the problem and solve it with open source solvers which use good heuristics

Comment: Well, whatever you said is quite new to me because I'm more of a beginner when dealing with serious algorithms, but I'll definitely try. And by the way we are allowed to write,compile and run the code only in DOS. So,I'll have to come up with something else.